# ¿Cómo plantear para que cada usuario tenga su propia url? dominio.com/juangarcia

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Dándole vueltas y vueltas no doy con el planteamiento de cómo hacer que cada usuario cuando se registre, su nombre sirva como parte de su propia url.
Ejemplo: Se registra Juan García, y que por registrarse en esa página, pueda hacer que tenga su url. dominio.com/juangarcia

Luego ya a cada url ya se encargaría de hacer la consultas correspondientes, etc. Eso creo que no tendré problema. ¿Pero cómo gener la url?

No se si debería crearse un archivo php, y claro, éste en un directorio entonces cada archivo php tener su consulta propia.
Quedaría algo así como: dominio.com/juangarcia/index.php de manera que si ponemos dominio.com/juangarcia se ejecutaría el index.php de su interior con la consulta correspondiente.

¿Qué os parece? ¿Cual sería el camino correcto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta depende de cómo estés estructurando tu código y de qué quieras meter en la sección de cada usuario. ¿Tienes un router centralizando el acceso o tienes el código repartido por carpetas? ¿Cada usuario tendrá sólo una url o varias (`dominio.com/juangarcía/<sección>`)? Y por último, ¿es un servidor Apache, Nginx, lighttpd, ...?

Comment: Es una aplicación web en php mysql (directorios y archivos php, html, jpg, etc.), y la idea es sacar mediante consulta la página de cada usuario (fotos, texto, etc.) La parte de consulta sql y mostrar no tengo problema, pero no se cómo convertir cada nombre de usuario en una url. No se si por cada usuario debería crear un directorio, y dentro del mismo un index.php que tenga la consulta (personalizada según usuario). Una vez sea cual sea el usuario, se ejecutaría por consulta el contenido del mismo con los join y where correspondientes. No se si me he expresado bien. Gracias delCano.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo entender que no tienes un solo punto de entrada (que te facilitaría mucho las cosas) y que además quieres que cada usuario tenga una sección completa, no una sola página. No has mencionado el servidor, que sería útil para hacerte una respuesta completa. Por tanto, te voy a dar solo una pista de hacia donde tirar: Lo ideal sería que cada usuario tenga una subruta (`dominio.com/u/juangarcia/<seccion>`) y que crees un `<userHandler>.php` que se ocupe de cargarlo a partir de un GET. Luego rediriges en la conf. del servidor desde `u/usuario` a `userHandler.php?u=usuario`.

Answer (score 0):

usa las sesiones de php para cada usuario ejemplo cuando un usuario se registre creas una session con el id de ese usuario

```
    $query1=mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO usuarios (name, lastname, etc...)
    VALUES ($variblename etc...); 

       if ($query1){ 
        session_start();
       $query=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM usuarios"); 

      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 

      $row["id"]=$_SESSION[id];
      $row["name"]=$_SESSION[usuario];
      //puedes crear todas las sessiones que quieras para cada campo
      //luego lo rediriges a la pagina para ese usuario ejemplo
    header("location,misession.php")//por ejemplo y despues creas  esearchivo

    /*misession.php y en ese archivo recives cada usuario con $_GET[id];*/
 }
 }
 ?>
```

lo demas dependera de que quieres hacer con la seccion de cada usuario pero asi obtendras lo que quieres midominio.com/usuario/fulano

Comment: Perdona, pero si he entendido bien, de esta manera es un inicio de sesión normal y cada usuario entraría a su sesión, vale, pero ¿cada uno tendría una url que podría compartir o mandar, o poner en su curriculum?